# Use bound this and this of function scope in a function bound with bind()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function call:

```
$(".selector").on("click", callback.bind(this, param1, param2));
```

Inside my callback function I would like to use the bound this as well as the this from the function scope.

Can this be done somehow?

Comment: Well, you can't bind two things to one `this`. You'll have to pass one or the other `this` as argument into the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Inside my callback function I would like to use the bound this as well as the this from the function scope.

In that **specific** example, you can use the `currentTarget` property of the event:

```
function callback(p1, p2, e) {
    // Use e.currentTarget
}
```

Note that there we have `p1` and `p2`, which are the arguments you bound to the callback, followed by `e` which is the event argument passed when the click occurs.

---

In the *general* case, though, you wouldn't want `Function#bind`, because it prevents your accessing the `this` that the function was called with.

You can provide yourself a `Function#curry` *(see below for why that name)* that leaves `this` alone, and then curry the current `this`, e.g.:

```
$(".selector").on("click", callback.curry(this, param1, param2));
```

Where an **unoptimized** version of `curry` looks like this:

```
Function.prototype.curry = function() {
    var f = this;
    var boundArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return function() {
        return f.apply(this, boundArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
    };
};
```

**Live Example:**

```js
Function.prototype.curry = function() {
  var f = this;
  var boundArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  return function() {
    return f.apply(this, boundArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
  };
};

var obj = {
  foo: 42,
  method: function() {
    $(".selector").on("click", callback.curry(this, "param1", "param2"));
  }
};
obj.method();

function callback(t, p1, p2, e) {
  snippet.log("t.foo = " + t.foo);
  snippet.log("this.tagName = " + this.tagName);
  snippet.log("e.currentTarget.tagName = " + e.currentTarget.tagName);
  snippet.log("p1 = " + p1);
  snippet.log("p2 = " + p2);
}
```

```html
<div class="selector">Click me</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

**Why `curry`?**

Creating a function from another function with (some of) that function's arguments pre-supplied is frquently called "currying," after the mathmatician Haskell Curry. It's also called "partial application" although I think (this is not my area of expertise) that term has a slightly more specific meaning, at least in functional programming (such as the kind you do in the language Haskell—  also named after Haskell Curry).

Comment: May I ask; why *curry*? (:

Comment: @George: Doh! Meant to put that in the answer. Because that's what the math operation is frequently called, after the mathematician Haskell Curry.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder lol because of your answer I actually understand the question, but still had to re-read it 3 times

Answer (score 0):

when this in your callback belongs to the scope of callback bind not the scope of the event.

this might work but I am not sure i understand what you are trying to do

```
$(".selector").on("click", function(event){
    callback.bind(event.type, param1, param2)
});
```

this points to the dom element your event occured
while the event already has the type which you want to pass to the 2nd bind (2nd because in theory your .on() is a bind as well)