# JavaScript Function.bind(): default this argument

Tags: javascript, function, event-handling, function-binding

The first parameter to the `bind` method is the new `this` value. The problem is that this appears to replace the natural `this` value. In particular, if used for an event listener, it is no longer the triggering element.

For example:

```
var h1=document.querySelector('h1')
h1.onclick=doit.bind(this,42);  //  or null, or h1
function doit(a) {
    alert(this);                //  Not automatically the calling element
    alert(a);
}
```

Now I know that in this case I can set the first parameter to the element `h1`; I can also use `event.target` to get the actual target. However that’s not always convenient, for example when assigning an event listener to multiple or anonymous elements.

The question is, is there a simple way to tell `bind` to use the default value of `this`?

Thanks

Note: This is *not* strictly a duplicate of [Use bound this and this of function scope in a function bound with bind()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32266774/use-bound-this-and-this-of-function-scope-in-a-function-bound-with-bind) as (a) The question asks whether it is possible to bind more than one version of `this` and (b) The accepted answer involves either using `event.currentTarget` which I sort of mentioned myself or writing a new method, which is not what I was asking.

However, it is possible that the answer is no, it can’t be done, so I won’t seek to re-open the question.

Comment: I found this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851088/how-to-bind-function-arguments-without-binding-this/16400626

Comment: @Lynn Thanks for the link. Short answer is create your own version, which is what I have been doing in the past, or forego the method and do it the old way by assigning a function expression.